# Salesforce iOS push notification SFREST API

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Now am workig on Salesforce MobileSDK iOS native App, for implement Push Notification am following below Link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_notifcations_push.htm

```
API                                             :  /connect/notifications/push
Request parameters for POST  :
{ "appName" : "sample",
"namespace" : "abc",
"userIds" : "005x00000013dHH",
"payload" : "{'aps':{'alert':'test', 'badge':0, 'sound':'default'}}"
}
```

But am getting below Error Message

> request:didFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=CSFNetworkErrorDomain
>   Code=400 "Can not deserialize: unexpected array at [line:3,
>   column:22]" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON_PARSER_ERROR,
>   isAuthenticationFailure=false, NSUnderlyingError=0x610000056770 {Error
>   Domain=CSFNetworkErrorDomain Code=400 "HTTP 400 for POST
>   /connect/notifications/push" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP 400
>   for POST /connect/notifications/push,
>   action=}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Can
>   not deserialize: unexpected array at [line:3, column:22],
>   action=}